# TestNG: How i can put parameters for java method on command line?

Tags: java, command-line, terminal, testng

I have test script like:

```
public class AppTest {
    @Test
    public void print(String strInput)
    {
        System.out.println("String: " + strInput);
    }
}
```

and Testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
      <class name="Test.printTest.AppTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

How I can put parameter on command line instead of on testng.xm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a [data provider](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) that will look for attributes in system properties:

```
public class AppTest {

  @DataProvider
  public static Object[][] dp() {
    String input = System.getProperty("input");
    return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { input }
    }
  }

  @Test(dataProvider="dp")
  public void print(String strInput) {
      System.out.println("String: " + strInput);
  }
}
```

Then, you just have to run it by adding `-Dinput="HelloWorld` param in your command line.